# savedpreferences not working on reboot on an android board

Tags: android, button, save, sharedpreferences

From last one week I am facing a strange problem with saved preferences.

I am working on a board which is android compatable.

The actual problem i am facing is,

I have 4 buttons and on the button click I am changing the background images of the button

Onfirstclick -> change the background image of the button to highlited -> second click ->change to normal background image and on first run I am keeping the normal background button image

but on reboot the button background images are not getting saved in my working board though I am using shared preferences.

I have a power button for on and off with which I am rebooting my board.

whatever Image(normal/highlited) I have in onclick that image I should get after rebooting the board

The good thing is that

```
           the code is working perfectly in android mobile but not in my board
```

this is my code.

Any help is always appreciated.

```
   public class SharedprefsActivity extends Activity  {

    protected static final String TAG = "HvacActivity";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Button seatdirnbtn;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private String prefName = "MyPref";
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private boolean isclick;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        seatdirnbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seatdirnbtn);      
        seatdirnbtn.setOnClickListener(listner1);       
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPrefAndButtonState();        
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        setPrefAndButtonState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        getPrefAndButtonState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        setPrefAndButtonState();
    }

    public void getPrefAndButtonState(){
        prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        isclick = prefs.getBoolean("prefName", false);
        System.out.println("bool? " + isclick);
        if (isclick) {
            seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4hlt);
        } else if (!isclick) {
            seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4);
        }
    }

    public void setPrefAndButtonState(){
        editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("prefName", isclick);
        editor.commit();        
        getPrefAndButtonState();
    }

    private View.OnClickListener listner1 = new View.OnClickListener() {    
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            if (isclick) {
                isclick = false;
                setPrefAndButtonState();            
            } else if (!isclick) {
                isclick = true;
                setPrefAndButtonState();
            }   
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I can't solve your problem, but I can tell you you can remove your `onStop()` and `onRestart()`. `onPause()` always gets called before `onStop()`, and you don't have to set the prefs twice. `onResume()` always gets called after `onRestart()`, so you're getting the prefs twice too.

EDIT: http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/app/doc-files/activity_lifecycle.png (just Google 'android activity lifecycle')

Comment: Thanks, but how its working perfectly in my mobile I dont understand.

Comment: I'm just saying those two methods are obsolete and can be removed without consequences. Since that doesn't answer your question though, I didn't post this as an answer. Because it is not.

Answer (score 2):

try using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`  as:

in `setPrefAndButtonState` method :

```
public void setPrefAndButtonState(){
      prefs = getApplicationContext().
                getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE); <<missing this line
      editor = prefs.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("prefName", isclick);
      editor.commit();        
      getPrefAndButtonState();
    }
```

and in `getPrefAndButtonState` method

```
public void getPrefAndButtonState(){
    prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
    isclick = prefs.getBoolean("prefName", false);
    System.out.println("bool? " + isclick);
    if (isclick) {
        seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4hlt);
    } else if (!isclick) {
        seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, but on first click I am getting the highlited image and on rebot I am getting the highlited image as I want. thats fine but with normal image  If I reboot I am getting the highlited image, which should not happen. here i want normal image only. any suggestions?

Comment: @Capricorn : problem is on reboot you want normal image right?

Comment: whatever background image I have before reboot I should get that after reboot. before reboot if I have normal background image then I should get the same after the reboot. and same for the highlited button  background also. here its working if i have highlited background before reboot but  not for normal background before reboot.

Comment: @Capricorn : just wait i'm changing your code according to your requirement.thanks

Comment: @Capricorn : which image is highlighted from icon4hlt or icon4?

Comment: , icon4hlt is highlited one

Comment: @Capricorn : one more question which image's you have added in Background by default for button in xml layout means image for seatdirnbtn button in xml

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K,  I have added  icon4  bydefault in xml

Comment: @Capricorn : i have not full code on my side so i send told you problem . you will also need to read SharedPreferences in onCreate of Activity to set last drawable again

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am checking the result in myboard

Comment: I tested it repeatedly, but its not working. I mean when the buton has  highlited background before reboot, its working, but if button has normal background before reboot its not working.I am getting highlited in this case.

Comment: here    if (isclick) {
        seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4hlt);
    } else if (!isclick) {
        seatdirnbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon4);
    } while debugging the control is not going to else part

Comment: @Capricorn : check sharedprefrences value in oncreate

Comment: its showing isclick = false everywhere in oncreate, while debugging.any suggestions?

Comment: earlier when I debugged the app, the isclick was showing true in oncreate. I dont understand about this strange behaviour.

Comment: Am I doing anything wrong in onclick(I mean wrong in changing the boolean value or something else).